# How to solve this exception?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, exception

I have been getting this exception, DatabaseObjectNotClosedException:

```
close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.project.test/databases/database' 
E/SQLiteDatabase(13921): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException:        
Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
```

I tried closing the database helper and cursors, but I will get runtime exception. This happens when I leave the activity and revisit it after hitting the back button.

How can I close my cursors and helpers properly?

I have tried two methods:

first, closing the cursors after each individual use, and closing the database helper onpause.

second, closing the cursors onpause along with the databasehelper, but both didn't work.

can someone help me with this?

EDIT:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    activity = this.getActivity();
    context = this.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    mDbHelper.open();
    populateList();
}

public void populateList() {
    directoryCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllRootDirectories();
    activity.startManagingCursor(directoryCursor);

    adapter = new DirectoryListAdapter(this.getActivity(), directoryCursor);
    this.setListAdapter(adapter);
}

                 ......


private UpdateDatabaseListener updateDatabaseListener = new UpdateDatabaseListener() {

    public void onUpdate(int from, int to) {

                .....

        findExistingRecordCursor = mDbHelper.findExistingRecords(from, to);
        activity.startManagingCursor(findExistingRecordCursor);
        if(findExistingRecordCursor.getCount() == 0) {

              ....

          }

  }
}
```

---

I have a database helper opened in the onCreate() function.
cursors used when populating the listview,
cursors used to find existing records,
cursors to get information.

---

UPDATE:

I have tried closing onPause and onDestroy, it still crashes with runtimeexception.

Comment: Can you please post your code

Comment: @Gaurav which part of the code do you actually need to see? cos it's really lots of code. i can see what i can paste.

Comment: @Gaurav i have written down where i have used databasehelper and cursors

Comment: @Gaurav i have added some code from my activity too.

Answer (score 0):

Are you closing the SQLiteDatabase object or not. If not try to close SQLiteDatabase Object like this

1. SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteHelper classobject.getWriteableDatabase();
2. // block of code
3. db.close();

and run your application.

Could you please post your code so that it will be more helpful to understand your problem.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i have added some information to the question. i tried closing my cursor on the onPause() method. When I leave for another activity and hit the back button. it throws me a runtime exception.

Comment: if i don't close, then it wouldn't have any problems other than that DatabaseObjectNotClosedException.

Comment: Try to shift your datbase helper to a new activity which extends SQLiteOpenHelper and then instantiate the SQLiteHelper in your main activity class. This is my thinking but i am not sure whether it will work or not.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply.
From what I see, you have opened the db using
    mDbHelpher.open()
After that you did populatelist()
did you try doing mDbHelpher.close() after that?

Same thing with the cursors. Because your error clearly says that the db or the cursor was left open.
As soon as you are done using the db, you should close. This should not give the problem even after you visit another activity and then press back button.

Also you said you get runtime exception when you close the db or the cursor. Is it the same exception or different?